# Can I make two html inputs break into their own line when there isn't enough room in their container using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox

Let say I have a container that has a dynamic width. Inside I have two inputs side by side; one has a min-width of 60px and the other has a min-width of 100px. If the container becomes smaller than 160px I would like the inputs to stack on top of each other. Is this possible with pure css?

```
    <div class="u-centerY u-fillRemaining">
       <div class="table-twoInputs">
           <input type="text" class="table-effort" placeholder="Effort" value="">
           <input type="text" id="row-1-position" value="$2">
       </div>
    </div>


.table-twoInputs {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;

    input {
        color: black;
        transition: none;

        &:first-of-type {
            text-align: left;
            left: 0;


            &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
                font-size: 10px;
                color: $table-gray;
            }

    // Browser quirk. These need to be separated out 
            &::-moz-placeholder {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: $table-gray;
            }

            ::-ms-placeholder {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: $table-gray;
            }
        }

        & + input {
            margin-left: 0.5rem;
            width: 150%;
        } 
    }
}
    .u-centerY {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center; 
    }

.u-fillRemaining {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that by dafult?

Comment: No, it's not. As far as I can tell inputs don't wrap. If I give them a min-width they simply break the container.

Comment: It is by default [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4u7pab8x/1/)

Comment: I have tried that just to be sure and it works for me by default.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I posted it before, but here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/4u7pab8x/2

Comment: See Marc Hjorth Laustsen's fiddle (it works even with min-width).

Comment: As simple as this seems, my inputs are breaking their container. Let me post my css as well.

Comment: As mentioned above the behaviour you're asking for occurs by default unless there is some misunderstanding with your question.

Comment: Okay, I'll mess with my code some more I must have some css on the container that is causing the behavior to alter.

Comment: Okay, this behavior does not happen when you use display flex. I need to use flexbox. Is there a way to do this with flexbox? @Daniel

Comment: @London804 update your question to specify that you're using `flexbox` and you want this line-break behaviour.

Comment: I updated the question. I tagged it with flexbox so I thought that would be sufficient.

Comment: It doesn't happen by default with flexbox because an initial setting in *flex layout* is `flex-wrap: nowrap`, which forces items to stay on a single line at all times. This is not the case in *block layout*, which is why the demos above wrap by default. See my answer.

Comment: Yep, I ended up figuring it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.table-twoInputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.one {
  width: 100px;
}

.two {
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-centerY u-fillRemaining">
  <div class="table-twoInputs">
    <input type="text" class="one" value="one">
    <input type="text" class="two" value="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4u7pab8x/4/